# Vim: delete tag + matching character WITHOUT deleting the text between them?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to delete a tag and its matching character **without** deleting the text between them?

Example: I have the following C code snippet:

```
int f(){
    # Some actions
    # multi line
    # bla bla bla
}
```

...and I wish to get the following code:

```
int f()
    # Some actions
    # multi line
    # bla bla bla
```

(I know this example is quite strange, but bare with me here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin called [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) that gives this functionality. You would
just do `ds{` to 'delete surrounding `{`'

The plugin also allows you to do things like `cs{]` to 'change surrounding `{}`
to `[]`'. That is change this:

```
{
"Hello world!"
}
```

to this:

```
[
"Hello world!"
]
```

You can also do it with single and double quotes e.g. `cs")` would 'change
surrounding `""` to `()`':

```
[
(Hello world!)
]
```

All of this works with with `ds`, `cs`, `ys` ('delete', 'change', 'yank')

And as a bonus, if you have the [repeat.vim plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat), the `.` command can be
used to repeat the edit elsewhere. This combination feels as natural to vim as
the built in text objects.